# Probability of a given sequence occurring

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a sequence of length $N$, that can consist of elements $\{H,M,S,X\}$. Every sequence contains exactly $5 H$'s. In my problem I refer to $H$ and $S$ as successes, and $M, X$ as failures. Up until the 5th and final $H$, the sequence can only contain $H$ and $M$. After that point it can only contain $S$ and $X$. I am trying to calculate the probability of all valid sequences with length $N$ and $T$ total successes. For a given $N$, summing over all possible number of successes ($0$ to $N$) will equal 1. For $T<5$ the problem is straight forward. For $T>4$ I attempted calculating by breaking the sequence into two parts: the start up to (and including) the 5th $H$ (call it $b$ elements), and the remainder (consisting of just $S$ and $X$). The first half of the sequence can be arranged in ${b \choose 5}$ and the second half can be arranged in ${N-b \choose T-5}$. Giving probability:
$${b \choose 5}{N-b \choose T-5}h^5(1-h)^{b-5}s^{T-5}(1-s)^{N-b-T+5}$$ Where $\{H,M,S,X\}$ occur with probabilities $h, 1-h, s,$ and $1-s$ respectively.
From here I thought I could sum over $b$ from the lowest possibility 5 to $N-T+5$.
I was wondering if my thinking is correct, and if so if there is a way to reduce this sum. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the probabilities mean here...clearly those values are dependent on other elements in the sequence.  nothing in what you have written tells us the probability of a given sequence, only whether or not the sequence is valid (given the constraints).

Comment: Consider the case $N=5$.  There is only one possible sequence, so it's probability is $1$, right?

Comment: Thanks,  I was worried that was worded in a confusing way, but am not sure best way to reword. An example of what I am looking for, is if I have the sequence $HHHHMHSS$ the probability would be $h^5(1-h)s^2$. Although in my problem I only know The sequence is a given length $N$, and there are $T$ total successes ($H+S=T$). Any advice on how to rephrase welcome. For $N=5$ probability would be $h^5$.

Comment: Trying to guess what you mean...are you saying that we generate a sequence randomly, according to those probabilities, with no regard for whether it passes the requirements, and then you are asking for the probability that it actually does happen to pass?  Obviously, there are very very few sequences which actually pass the tests...

Comment: Again, I assumed that, since you said "every sequence contains exactly..." that you were speaking of *conditional* probability.  That is, you wanted the probability that a given sort of sequence occurred *given that* we knew it passed the tests.  In that case the probability of $H^5$ would be $1$, since that is the only option.  Maybe you meant something else...

Comment: In addition to the problems rightly pointed out by @lulu above, those four probabilities add up to $2$, so they can't be the probabilities of four mutually exclusive events (as "elements ... which occur with probabilities ..." might have suggested) – what are they the probabilities of?

Comment: Yes @lulu, sorry about that. I tried to edit my question to clarify (hope it did). For $N=5$ it would be 1 given I am looking at the set where 5 successes occurred, but I neglected to mention I am considering 0-4 successes elsewhere (I understood how to do that part). Sorry again.

Comment: You still haven't explained the "probability" here.  As the comments have pointed out, what you say doesn't make sense.  Best guess I can come up with:  you don't mean *exactly* $5$ $H's$, that's what's causing all the problems.  You mean *at most* five.  Then you can say "you first do $H,M$ according to a binomial process then, if you get to $5$ $H's$ you stop and start doing $S,X$ according to a possibly different binomial process.  That makes sense...what you wrote does not.

Comment: To stress:  if you insist on *exactly* $5$ then the trials simply can't be independent, since the process somehow "knows" that it needs to produce $5$ $H's$.  And you haven't explained how the dependence works.  If you go with *at most* $5$, then the trials can be independent, but then of course $MMM$ is a perfectly good sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you tried to restate your question but it's still rather confusing. Would the following be essentially equivalent to what you're asking?

There are two unfair coins; the first has $H$ on one side and $M$ on the other, the second has $S$ on one side and $X$ on the other. The probability of getting an $H$ with the first coin is $h$, and the probability of getting an $S$ with the second coin is $s$; we define those two outcomes ($H$'s and $S$'s) as 'successes'. We flip the first coin until we get our fifth $H$, then we switch to the second coin and continue until we've made a total of $N$ coin flips. What's the probability of getting $T$ successes?

If the above interpretation is correct, then there is only one small change you need to make to the answer you gave: since you know that the $b$'th term in your sequence will be an $H$, the first binomial coefficient in your calculation should be $\binom{b-1}{4}$ rather than $\binom{b}{5}$.

Otherwise, I would agree that the answer would be

$$\sum_{b=5}^{N-T+5} \binom{b-1}{4}\binom{N-b}{T-5}h^5(1-h)^{b-5}s^{T-5}(1-s)^{N-b-T+5}$$

As for simplifying the sum, I'm not sure there is a way to do that, maybe someone else will have a suggestion.